# CAST or Convert Within a SUM and Case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it correct to implement a cast or convert in an aggregate SUM with a Case and if so, how would be the correct way to implement them? For example

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN X = 'Y' THEN Z ELSE 0.00 END)
```

In this case Z would be Cast or Converted, it is Datatype numeric, I'd like to convert it to varchar

Comment: Uh, one doesn't normally sum varchars, so I would leave it as numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to `sum` your values first, then display the result as `varchar`, you'll want to do it like this:

```
Cast(Sum(case when x = y then z else 0 end) as varchar(10))
```

If you `cast` first, you may get unexpected results from your `sum`, or get an error.  For example, trying to execute `sum(cast([IntegerColumn] as varchar))` returns:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thank you! I wanted to display the results as varchar to add $ in front of it